# How to split and display ajax data in two div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display two sets of data on two div's with ajax.

I'm using below code to do this.

Here is the ajax code

```
   $(function () {
    $(".myBtn").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&list_id=' + <? php echo $id; ?> ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name == 'up') {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_up.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    parent.parent().find(".v-up").html(json.msg1);
                    parent.parent().find(".v-down").html(json.msg2);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn(200).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "vote_down.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    parent.parent().find(".v-down").html(json.msg2);
                    parent.parent().find(".v-up").html(json.msg1);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is the jason code

```
echo json_encode(array('msg1'=>$value1));
return;

echo json_encode(array('msg1'=>$value2));
return;
```

Code does'nt seems to be working.  It shows the msg1 but it doesn't show the msg2

Can someone one point me out how to do this or what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "Code doesn't seem to be working" - What isn't working? What error are you getting in the console? What line is the code failing on?

Comment: That small amount of PHP isn't enough. It looks like you're returning from a function, and have more code below, which of course will not be executed.

Comment: @brso05 It shows the msg1 but it doesn't show the msg2. that is the issue. Code must display both the data at once.

Comment: @nickcruse that still doesn't help **WHY** isn't it showing the other message? There must be some error or perhaps you aren't returning anything from your web service for `msg2`...

Comment: Apart from the question, I don't think this is valid: `'&list_id=' + <? php echo $id; ?> ;`

Comment: @Artur Filipiak i didnt add list_id and all that because its all work fine. Only issue is that only one value is updating not both the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the minimal amount of PHP that you've given it looks like you want to do this instead

```
echo json_encode(array('msg1'=>$value1, 'msg2'=>$value2));
return;
```

which means when you try access the values, as you have

```
success: function (json) {
    parent.parent().find(".v-down").html(json.msg2);
    parent.parent().find(".v-up").html(json.msg1);
}
```

they will be there

Comment: @brso05 I disagree, he's using `json.msg1` and `json.msg2`

Comment: i tried this code but still updating only one sets of data.

Comment: What are you trying to update?

Comment: its some votes. example v-down will display down votes and v-up will display up votes

Comment: Then you haven't provided enough information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make both json-strings to one and split them up in the scriptwork.
Also you should look, that there is nothing more put out than the json-String.
for example like this:
//PHP

```
$array = array("msg1"=>$value1, "msg2"=>$value2);
$toJSON = json_encode($array);
echo $toJSON;
die(); // To prevent more output after this json-String
```

//JS

```
[...]
success: function (json) {
                    parent.parent().find(".v-down").html(json.msg2);
                    parent.parent().find(".v-up").html(json.msg1);
                }
[...]
```

Comment: please don't post duplicate answers

Comment: @Popnoodles yes there is an `echo`.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see the previous Answer while writing.

Comment: @Lacrioque it's alright don't worry about it. There is no reason to downvote this answer whoever downvoted should specify why otherwise the downvote isn't helping anyone.

Comment: given the information in the question, this answer works so I'm giving it a +1, and good luck with the follow-up questions from nick cruse.

Comment: @Lacrioque still the same issue. Only displaying(uptdating) one value. Php is sending out the correct output Ex: `{"msg1":"1","msg2":"0"}`

Comment: @nickcruse **you have not given enough information for us to fix that** Maybe it's that `.v-down` doesn't exist.

Comment: have you tried to console out the output and the elements you want to change?